# How do you check if IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or OFF in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-insert

I've searched for this, but threads in which it appeared tended to have answers from people who didn't understand the question.

Take the following syntax:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON
```

How do you do something more like this:

```
GET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1
```

I don't want to do anything whatsoever to the data in the database or to the settings to get this information though.  Thanks!

Comment: Funny how you mentioned people misunderstanding the question and the vast majority of answers here doing exactly that.

Comment: For you & others googling this, the real question:  *sessions*. You would probably only want to check/restore the value of IDENTITY_INSERT for a *session* long & complicated enough to allow and later prevent identity inserts.  (A continuously running job step?)  BECAUSE if you start a new session, `IDENTITY_INSERT` is off!  If you're not clear whether something stays the same session, google sessions (not exactly = connections), check out `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections`, or download `sp_WhoIsActive` and `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @show_sleeping_spids = 2, @show_own_spid = 1`

Comment: One quick way to determine if the flag is on or off is by attempting to make the insert.  If the insert succeeds, the flag was 'on'.  If it fails, SSMS will display "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '<table name>' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is a session sensitive, it is managed in buffer level without storing somewhere. This means we do not need to check the `IDENTITY_INSERT` status as we never use this key word in current session.

Sorry, no help for this.

Great question though :)

Source: [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/1a6ba2bb-5e82-47e8-a1a0-16fc044b951e)

**Update**
There are ways maybe to do this, also seen in the site I linked, IMO, it is too much effort to be useful.

```
if

(select max(id) from MyTable) < (select max(id) from inserted)

--Then you may be inserting a record normally

BEGIN
    set @I = 1 --SQL wants something to happen in the "IF" side of an IF/ELSE
END

ELSE --You definitely have IDENTITY_INSERT on.  Done as ELSE instead of the other way around so that if there is no inserted table, it will run anyway


BEGIN
.... Code that shouldn't run with IDENTITY_INSERT on
END
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just learned that it exists yesterday, so I'm not real sure how to apply what you're saying.  Basically we have two databases on two different servers, and shutting down either one and restarting it is going to be a problem.  Does the session you're referring to last more than a couple of minutes if the database service is left running indefinitely?  Basically I set the value a few times on one of the databases without taking notes beforehand, and I need to make sure that any change like that is rolled back.

Comment: Note that this is not an answer of my own, but from my source at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/1a6ba2bb-5e82-47e8-a1a0-16fc044b951e (official Microsoft forums, have tons of those bookmarked.) It all depends on the performance on these servers. Obviously, if the servers are slow/ the services regarding the SQL Server is shutting down, this code (in pseudo here) will not work out well. Why do you exactly need to know the Identity state of the tables ?

If the service runs indefinitely, this session should not last long (depending on server spec and table size)...

Comment: I'm just trying to reset the database back to the way it was before I started messing with the IDENTITY_INSERT values.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx Contains a great Explanation what Identity_Insert is. 

Tell me, did your databases break or something, when the server restarted, and if yes, why not attempt to restore it from a backup?
I pray you do have backups :O

Comment: Looks like everything's fine.  I'm just not familiar with more technical aspects of SQL, so that's where some my difficulty was coming from.  Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

In summary:

- [Nathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696778/1501497) is the fastest:

  ```
  SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('MyTable'), 'TableHasIdentity');
  ```

  - when using an API wrapper, one can reduce the entire check to just checking for rows. For instance when using C#'s `SqlDataReaders`  property `HasRows` and a query construct like:

    ```
    SELECT CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('MyTable'), 'TableHasIdentity')
           WHEN 1 THEN '1' ELSE NULL END
    ```
- [Ricardo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377081/1501497) allows more flexibility but requires the Column's identity name

  ```
  SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') 
                          AND name = 'MyTableIdentityColumnName';
  ```
- Bogdan Bodanov solution, using `try`/`catch` would work as well, but additional checking should confine exception handling to cases of  `IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'MyTable'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'MyTable';`

Comment: Non-solutions can't be fastest - neither Nathan's nor Ricardo's solutions actually address the problem. They test whether an identity column exists, not whether IDENTITY_INSERT is on or off for that column in the current session.

Answer (score 12):

You can discover whether or not identity_insert is on, and if so for what table using the code below.

```
declare @tableWithIdentity varchar(max) = '';
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ExampleTable ON

begin try
  create table #identityCheck (id int identity(1,1))
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT #identityCheck ON
  drop table #identityCheck
end try
begin catch
  declare @msg varchar(max) = error_message()
  set @tableWithIdentity= @msg;
  set @tableWithIdentity = 
  SUBSTRING(@tableWithIdentity,charindex('''',@tableWithIdentity,1)+1, 10000)

  set @tableWithIdentity = SUBSTRING(@tableWithIdentity,1, charindex('''',@tableWithIdentity,1)-1)

  print @msg;
  drop table #identityCheck
end catch

if @tableWithIdentity<>''
begin
  print ('Name of table with Identity_Insert set to ON: ' + @tableWithIdentity)
end
else
begin
  print 'No table currently has Identity Insert Set to ON'
end
```

Comment: @Graeme: thanks, I thought an actual answer to the question might be useful and that's the only way I know to do it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're attempting to turn off IDENTITY_INSERT for some other table to avoid getting an error when you want to set IDENTITY_INSERT on, the following may also work for you. As other have said on this thread IDENTITY_INSERT is a session setting with no direct visibility. However I made the interesting discovery that SET IDENTITY_INSERT  OFF doesn't error out for any table that has an identity whether or not IDENTITY_INSERT is ON for that table. So it occurred to me that I could just call SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... OFF for every table with an identity in the database. It feels a bit like a brute force solution, but 
I found that the following dynamic SQL block did the trick very nicely.

```
---- make sure IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF ----
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cmd = CAST((SELECT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + 
             QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + '.' + 
             QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' OFF' + CHAR(10)
             FROM sys.columns c 
             JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
             WHERE c.is_identity = 1 
             ORDER BY 1 FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
```

Comment: That *is* a brute force solution. And I humbly fail to see in which scenarios it would be both necessary and safe. If a call to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on was made within the calling script (or prior), there's most certainly a reason for it. :p Assuming that the caller won't keep relying on the info thereafter is wrong and potentially hazardous. Design wise, it would be best IMHO to simply try setting it on anyway and let the whole thing crash and burn if it must. At least devs will have a clue on what went wrong - assuming errors are logged somewhere.

Comment: That being said, I won't vote down because I still think your answer may be helpful for someone working his way around an app to fix db related issues. But that really is the only scenario I can think of. Of course, feel free to tell me if I'm missing on something. :)

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I Have same issue. May be you can try to reset IDENTITY_INSERT using TRY/CATCH? For example, you make the job but not sure if the job is finished and IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Why you don't try:

```
BEGIN TRY 
...
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF;
END CATCH;
```

Also I am not sure that this is working correctly but I see that adding only `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... OFF` did not return error. So you can set just in case in the end `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about the session variable... Good question, but I cant see where this information would be usefull. In normal execution to check a normal table response to an insert, this should work!

-- If you only want to know if there is identity insert on a given table:

```
select is_identity
from sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') and name = 'column_Name'
```

-- Or... Use this if you want to execute something depending on the result:

```
if exists (select *
from sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') and is_identity = 1)
... your code considering identity insert
else
... code that should not run with identity insert
```

Have fun!

Comment: This misses the point, the question is regarding whether `IDENTITY_INSERT` is on not if the table has an identity column

Comment: `is_identity` column in the `sys.columns` table identifies whether that column is an identity column or not, not whether the variable `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `ON` or `OFF`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It is very similar to @jmoreno's answer.

You would call it like this

```
DECLARE @IdentityInsert VARCHAR(20)
EXEC dbo.GetIdentityInsert 'YourDb', 'YourSchema', 'YourTable', @IdentityInsert OUT
SELECT @IdentityInsert
```

This returns a 1-row recordset with column name IDENTITY_INSERT, that can be either ON, OFF, or NO_IDENTITY (if the given table doesn't have an identity column). It also sets the output parameter @IdentityInsert. So you can adjust the code to whichever method you prefer.

It would be nice to get this into a user-defined function, but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to avoid the TRY..CATCH block, which you cannot use in user-defined functions.

```
-- ================================================================================
-- Check whether the table specified has its IDENTITY_INSERT set to ON or OFF.
-- If the table does not have an identity column, NO_IDENTITY is returned.
-- Tested on SQL 2008.
-- ================================================================================
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetIdentityInsert

      @dbname sysname
    , @schemaname sysname
    , @table sysname
    , @IdentityInsert VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @OtherTable nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @DbSchemaTable nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT;
    DECLARE @object_id INT;

    SET @DbSchemaTable = @dbname + '.' + @schemaname + '.' + @table

    SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(@DbSchemaTable)
    IF @object_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('table %s doesn''t exist', 16, 1, @DbSchemaTable)
        RETURN
    END


    BEGIN TRY

        SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(@DbSchemaTable)

        IF OBJECTPROPERTY(@object_id,'TableHasIdentity') = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @IdentityInsert = 'NO_IDENTITY'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Attempt to set IDENTITY_INSERT on a temp table. This will fail if any other table
            -- has IDENTITY_INSERT set to ON, and we'll process that in the CATCH
            CREATE TABLE #GetIdentityInsert(ID INT IDENTITY)
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT #GetIdentityInsert ON
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT #GetIdentityInsert OFF
            DROP TABLE #GetIdentityInsert

            -- It didn't fail, so IDENTITY_INSERT on @table must set to OFF
            SET @IdentityInsert = 'OFF'
        END
    END TRY


    BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

        IF @ErrorNumber = 8107  --IDENTITY_INSERT is already set on a table
        BEGIN
            SET @OtherTable = SUBSTRING(@ErrorMessage, CHARINDEX(char(39), @ErrorMessage)+1, 2000)
            SET @OtherTable = SUBSTRING(@OtherTable, 1, CHARINDEX(char(39), @OtherTable)-1)

            IF @OtherTable = @DbSchemaTable 
            BEGIN
                -- If the table name is the same, then IDENTITY_INSERT on @table must be ON
                SET @IdentityInsert = 'ON'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- If the table name is different, then IDENTITY_INSERT on @table must be OFF
                SET @IdentityInsert =  'OFF'
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (@ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
            --THROW     Use this if SQL 2012 or higher
        END

    END CATCH

    SELECT [IDENTITY_INSERT] = @IdentityInsert
END
GO
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also use the ObjectProperty method to determine if a table has an identity:

```
DECLARE @MyTableName nvarchar(200)
SET @MyTableName = 'TestTable'
SELECT CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@MyTableName), 'TableHasIdentity') 
WHEN 1 THEN 'has identity' 
ELSE 'no identity columns' 
END as HasIdentity
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. That's I had been searching

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't answer the question. This will check for the state of `TableHasIdentity` value as defined on the table, *not* the actual session-stored `IDENTITY_INSERT` value, which is what the op is looking for. Try for yourself: have a query that checks for the property, then alter the `IDENTITY_INSERT` value for the table and then get the object property again. Its value will still be the same as it was before.

Comment: The above code does not show whether the identity insert is ON or OFF